# How ccache improves building speed?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, ccache

I am using cmake to setup my project and when I change a file in a project, I found my cmake knows to only recompile the changed file and then relink everything together for the final executable/lib.

I then read through the documentation about ccache, what I don't understand is: what is the difference between ccache's approach (that uses hash value to check if file is changed and needs recompile) and the default approach that the cmake uses (or there might be something else rather than cmake checks the file updates, but you know what I mean here). Maybe the PCH part is different, but cmake 3.18 now comes with PCH support, so, does that mean the benefits ccache provides on the PCH part is no longer unique?

Comment: *"I found my cmake knows to only recompile the changed file"* - are you sure that it is not build system used during generation process, such as make or ninja, knows?

Comment: it is ninja that i am using, so it is ninja, i believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case where you switch to some older branch of your project - that you did compile in the past and that ccache has cached, but CMake sees as "almost all files have changed and must be recompiled" - that's where you see a massive gain.

Another situation is where you have deleted your build directory (for *some* good reason) and now have to rebuild everything. `ccache` is also a *huge* help there.

Also; `ccache` is trivial to set up and is thenceforth completely invisible / transparent, so there really is *no reason* to not use it. When it helps it usually helps a lot, when it does not help it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

`cmake`/`gmake` and `ccache` are not exclusive to each other. They are typically used together.

`ccache` comes into play when the ***entire*** source tree needs to be rebuilt for some reason. `cmake`/`gmake` rebuilds only changed files, but there are situations where the entire source tree needs to be recompiled. And if this happens repeatedly, `ccache` will wake up and short-circuit the compiler. C++ compilers are notorious for being slow, and this often helps quite a bit.

Just a couple of examples: when you need to repeatedly switch between building with and without optimizations, repeatedly. `cmake`/`gmake` won't help you when you edit the makefile and adjust the compilation flags. None of the source files actually changed, so `cmake`/`gmake` doesn't think there's anything to do, so you must explicitly `make clean` and recompile from scratch.

If you are doing it repeatedly, `ccache` will avoid having to run the compiler on the entire source code, and will simply fetch out the appropriate object module instead of compiling the source from scratch.

Another common situation is when you're running a script to prepare an installable package for your code. This typically involves using an implementation-specific tool to rebuild the source code, from scratch, into an installable package.